# custom url entry for webview through menu

Tags: android, webview, custom-url

I want to make my webview load a url that i enter through a dialogue that appears when i click on settings 
see the snap shot of my application https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5_GLYlww--PdDZvLXRZbWtmM1k/edit?usp=sharing

```
package com.example.rpitomate;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.2.101/test/index.html");
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_about:
        // About option clicked.
        AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();  
        ad.setCancelable(false); // This blocks the 'BACK' button  
        ad.setMessage("Application Developed By Chaitanya Allam");  
        ad.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  
                dialog.dismiss();                      
            }  
        });  
        ad.show();  
        return true;
    case R.id.action_exit:
        // Exit option clicked.
        return true;
    case R.id.action_settings:
        // Settings option clicked.
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
  }


  }
```

what should i write at case R.id.action_settings

Answer (score 0):

you want to start another activity, which is dedicated for settings. 
Start an intent. 
Eg:

```
Intent iSettings = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
```

In here, i use `SettingsActivity` as an activity.
Now, start the activity.

```
startActivity(iSettings);
```

for more info, visit [Android developers](http://developers.android.com) site.